# How do i plot facet plots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization, facet

This is what I have right now:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
test = pd.DataFrame({'week': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                     'score': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 12),
                     'type': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     'type2': [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]})

test.groupby(['week', 'type', 'type2']).agg('sum').unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

How do I plot facet based on 'type'? I want two different plots, one for type = 1 and another type = 2.

Comment: You might take a look at seaborn (based on pandas and matplotlib) http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to unstack so `type` are columns, and then use the `subplots` parameter:

```
test.groupby(['week', 'type', 
              'type2']).agg('sum').unstack(1).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)
```

[image: Resulting plot]